# Visual Studio 2012 toolkit missing LongListMultiSelector WP8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, nuget, toolkit

I am doing an app for windows phone 8 and would like to have a LongListMultiSelector in it but the toolkit does not contain it for what can see, anyone who knows why? i have installet it and added the reference and everything. I can find all the features that are made for WP7 but not for the newer features in WP8

Comment: There's a possibility NuGet is pulling in a package targeting the wrong phone OS. I've encountered the problem before but didn't document a way to clear this up, as it mysteriously righted itself after some time. To verify if this is the case, the path to your package would probably look like: `\packages\WPtoolkit.4.2012.10.30\lib\wp7`.

Comment: Thanks but it was apperently in wp 8 when i looked att the refference and when I had looked at it, suddenly it worked.